# How can I replace .append with pd.concat in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder how to replace the .append in a loop.

```
for i in range(0,len(DF)):
        result = result.append({'Test': DF.iloc[i].name},ignore_index=True)
```

I know how to use `CONCAT` but I don't understand how to do it in a loop.

Using `Concat` :

```
for i in range(0,len(DF)):
        result = pd.concat([result,pd.DataFrame({'Test': DF.iloc[i].name})])
```

Throw :

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: what you need to do exactly ? you need to provide full code so we can understand

Comment: @khaledkoubaa I want to replace append to avoid warning : `The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.`

But I don't know how to use `CONCAT` in a loop.

Comment: Why don't just append dataframes in a list and use concat outside the loop?

Comment: @rpanai Because it will throw warning.

Comment: really? Do you mind to produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @rpanai I already solved my issue [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73786557/11167163) thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put `[]` :

```
for i in range(0,len(DF)):
        result = pd.concat([result,pd.DataFrame({'Test': [DF.iloc[i].name]})])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(DF)):
        result = pd.concat([result, {'Test': DF.iloc[i].name})
```

Comment: it throw : ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index